# How could it be possible to read and write past the array

Tags: c, arrays, indexing, size

Output of the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int size;

    printf("Enter the size of array: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);

    int b[size],i = 0;
    printf("Enter %d integers to be printed: ",size);
    while(i++ < size)
    {
        scanf("%d",&b[i]);
        printf("%d     %d\n", i, b[i]);
    }
    return 0;       
}
```

for `size = 5` and input numbers :

```
0    1    2    3    4
```

is

```
1    0
2    1
3    2
4    3
5    4
```

where first column is for `i` and second for elements of array `b`.
It is clear that `i` in the loop `while(i++ < size) {` incremented to `1` before entering the loop. This loop should have to store/print the value at/of `b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4]` but not `b[5]` as loop will terminate at `i = 5`.
**How this code is printing the value of `b[5]`?**
I have tested it for different array `size` and it is not printing any garbage value.

Comment: UB != obligatory crash.

Comment: @H2CO3; no undefined behavior, I have tested it many times before posting.

Comment: Yes, it **does** invoke UB. And still, UB != obligatory crash.

Comment: You're just lucky that setting `b[5]` does not mix up other things.

Comment: @haccks BASIC. (I'm sorry.)

Comment: @H2CO3; Yes dude it is basic for me!

Comment: @haccks No, I mean I started with the BASIC programming language. Then Pascal, then some web stuff (less seriously), then some Python (even less seriously), then I skipped the Java step and got started with C and Objective-C, picking up some slices of C++ along the way.

Comment: @haccks You don't know what the BASIC programming language is? o.O

Comment: @haccks [Obligatory Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33451/discussion-between-h2co3-and-haccks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reading and writing past the array, your program invokes undefined behavior. It doesn't mean that it **has to** crash or print garbage values, it can pretend working fine. Apparently, that's what is happening in this case.

Comment: @H2CO3 First time I heard that ***It doesn't mean that it has to crash or print garbage values, it can pretend working fine***

Comment: @haccks Of course it can. Undefined is undefined because it's not **defined to crash.** That's quite logical I think.

Comment: @H2CO3; Ya, this is quite logical. Before today I was under impression  UB means either **crash** or **garbage value**!
Thanks for your valuable answer.(I was not expecting such answer!!

Comment: @haccks Well, just think about the meaning of the word :)

Comment: @H2CO3; You mean about UB?

Comment: @haccks Yes, IB means that it can produce different results depending on the compiler, the architecture, the OS, etc., but it must work *somehow.* UB is *permitted* to crash.

Comment: @haccks Yes, you've already told me that. Specifically **what?**

Comment: @haccks The best option is the language you could learn the best with the less effort. You, and only you can decide that. (I don't recommend Java, though -- it's a horrible language with even worse implementations IMO, but some people find it easier than Objective-C or C++.)

Comment: @haccks Java is pretty much dead (except on Android... -.-"). Learn both Objective-C and C++ and you'll good to go.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40015/discussion-between-h2co3-and-haccks)

Answer (score 1):

In your loop, the condition `i < size` is checked before `i` is incremented. But, `i` is incremented before entering the body of the loop and not after it, so it is possible to access `b[5]` in this case, as `i` would be incremented after checking `i < size` with `i=4`. You do not want that, as this causes undefined program behavior.

If you try to access an element in the array which does not exist, e.g. `array[size]`, you are accessing the next spot in the memory right after the array. In this case you are lucky, but if this meant you were accessing a part of the memory where your program isn't allowed to do so, you'd get a `segmentation fault`.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a **for** cycle instead of a **while** so instead of `while(i++<size)`you could use `for(i = 0; i < size; i++)` that should solve your problem my friend :)