# Output of a C string program

Tags: c, string, printf, output, character-arrays

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char s[2]="a";
  s[1]='b';s[2]='c';s[3]='d';s[5]='e';
  printf("%s $%c$",s,s[4]);
  return 0;
 }
```

1.When I run this program in C (gcc-4.7.2) I expected Runtime Error because of the missing Null Character ('\0').

2.If still the program compiles and executes successfully ,since s[4] has not been initialised,I expected some garbage value at that place..but here also I was wrong.

The output of the above program is: 
abcde $$
There is no character between the two $(dollor) which indicates printf skips s[4].
here is a ideone link for the same:
http://ideone.com/UUQxb2

Explain the reason for this behaviour (output) ?

Comment: your program should give compilation errors. Because, s[4] or s[5] don't exist when s is just made of 2 elements

Comment: The location s[4] might simply have had an unprintable character.

Comment: @AswinMurugesh: I have given the ideone link in the question.It is compiling and executing successfully.

Comment: I can't understand this behaviour. How does this work?

Comment: I'm guessing that it's one of those Array out of bounds weird behaviour of the Ideone compiler.

Comment: @KyleT: I get this point.I was not known about Non-printable characters.Thanks for that.
Still I am confused how the string prints abcde when there is no null character after 'e'.
and if i take char s[2]="abcde"; in this case it does not give any output.

Comment: @user2521673 Try using a loop for printing all characters with the values 0 to 255. You will find many new characters.

Comment: I'm thinking that there just happened to be a null terminator immediately after s[5] in memory, so your string printed until it encountered it. Like others have said, it's undefined behavior, so hard to tell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How could it be possible to read and write past the array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413252/how-could-it-be-possible-to-read-and-write-past-the-array).

Answer (score 1):

You are writing/reading outside of the bounds of the array, this is simply [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) you can not make any predictions about what the program will do.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing out of bound of an array is undefined behaviour. Just an example same code's output on my system is `abcd(e▒x $($`

string of length 8 is because of lack of NULL terminator and character `(` between `$` is garbage value of `s[4]`.

Answer (score 0):

1. It isn't necessary for a runtime error to occur. C does no bound checking.
2. There are many characters defined in C. Like the sound beep `\a` if I remebember correct so it isn't necessary that something is actually printed on the screen. It might have been a sound that you never heard.