# Array index greater than the declared value. How is it possible?

Tags: c

I came across the following code in another question. the array is declared as `char s[2];` and the code contains the statement `s[3]=d;`. How does [this](http://ideone.com/UUQxb2) code work correctly?

Comment: Please post your code here.  Don't send us elsewhere.

Comment: [last asked & answered yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413252/how-could-it-be-possible-to-read-and-write-past-the-array/17413330#17413330), why you guys can't use Google?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not work.  If it does something, it's blind luck.  And the full [code is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432222/output-of-a-c-string-program).

Comment: see the code link i have posted

Comment: +1 to counteract someone's downvote.  This answer might be terse, but it's correct.

Comment: @AswinMurugesh It's on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432222/output-of-a-c-string-program) also actually, just a minute ago.  Weird.

Comment: @AswinMurugesh In case you downvoted: don't. "It works" and "you think it works" are different, and **you are downright wrong when you insist it indeed works.**

Comment: @H2CO3: i did not downvote. why do you target me?

Comment: @AswinMurugesh Only because you refused to accept the assertion that the code does not work.

Comment: @H2CO3: Leave that. Its not me

Comment: @AswinMurugesh Please accept this answer if you agree ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It's undefined behaviour - it could do anything. In practice you're apparently unlucky and it doesn't crash to warn you that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: +1 for the unlucky part. Very true.

Answer (score 0):

It is nothing but `Undefined Behavior`. I tried this code but it didn't work on my PC. It entirely depends on the compiler, environment. Your code is an example of a code whose behavior is unpredictable. i.e. `Different output on different environment.`

Answer (score 0):

In C you are often able to do things that are "illegal" in the eyes of other compilers.  This will result in "undefined behavior" and should be avoided.

If you read or write outside of the array bounds on most operating systems it will appear to "work" and not complain.  Unless you are lucky and are at the edge of a memory page, then you could be doing this erroneously and the OS will crash your program.

I like to envision the memory as a library.  Pretend with me for a moment that your operating system is the librarian.  If you ask the librarian where a book should go, she may tell you a certain shelf and a certain section.  It is up to you to place your book back in the appropriate section.  If you misplace it, you will likely get away with it unless the librarian (OS) catches you and scolds you for your error.  Otherwise, the book will now be placed in the false location until it gets moved (overwritten).  In something as large as the RAM of most computers, you will not ruin the entire library of data by having one incorrect byte, but it is likely that if you encounter this misplaced data (book) again that you will get messed up results, corrupted files, potential crashes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this in Visual Studio 2010:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int s[2];

    s[0] = 0;
    s[1] = 1;
    s[2] = 2;

    for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        printf("%d", s[i]);
}
```

Only after the entire main() was finished, Visual Studio threw a "Stack Corrupted" error. In short, the behavior is undefined.