# Why can an array receive values more than it is declared to hold

Tags: c, arrays, undefined-behavior

```
int main(void)
{
    char name1[5];
    int count;
    printf("Please enter names\n");
    count = scanf("%s",name1);
    printf("You entered name1 %s\n",name1);
    return 0;
}
```

When I entered more than 5 characters, it printed the characters as I entered, it was more than 5, but the char array is declared as:

```
char name1[5];
```

Why did this happened

Comment: This is undefined behavior, anything can happen including a program that seems to work.

Comment: Try to enter a very large string. Your program is very likly to crash because it will overwrite the return address of the main function on the stack.

Comment: Ever wondered how computer break-ins happen? Your program shows one side of the "how". The other side is explained [in an article on Stack Buffer Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow).

Comment: Read: [Reading a line using scanf() not good?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294809/reading-a-line-using-scanf-not-good)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How could it be possible to read and write past the array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413252/how-could-it-be-possible-to-read-and-write-past-the-array).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because the characters are stored on the addresses after the 'storage space'. This is very dangerous and can lead to crashes.

E.g. suppose you enter name: Michael and the name1 variable starts at 0x1000.

```
name1: M       i     c      h      a      e      l     \0
      0x1000 0x1001 0x1002 0x1003 0x1004 0x1005 0x1006 0x1007
      [................................]
```

The allocated space is shown with [...]
This means from 0x1005 memory is overwritten.

**Solution:**

Copy only 5 characters (including the \0 at the end) or check the length of the entered string before you copy it.

Comment: add for OP: use instead `fgets (name1, 4, stdin);` is safe

Comment: Or `fgets(name1,sizeof name1,stdin);` even better :)

Comment: @PHIfounder but if he wants to use as string it should be : `fgets(name1, sizeof name1 - 1, stdin);`

Comment: `scanf(%4s",name1);` will also do the job.

Answer (score 6):

This is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), you are writing beyond the bounds of allocated memory. Anything can happen, including a program that appears to work correctly.

The C99 draft standard section `J.2` *Undefined Behavior* says:

> The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:

and contains the following bullet:

> An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently accessible with the
>   given subscript (as in the lvalue expression a[1][7] given the declaration int a[4][5]) (6.5.6).

This applies to the more general case since E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2))).

Answer (score 2):

This is undefined behavior, you can't count on it. It just happens to work, it may not work on another machine.

To avoid buffer overflow, use

```
fgets(name1, sizeof(name1) - 1, stdin);
```

or in C11

```
gets_s(name1, sizeof(name1) - 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

another example to make things clearer :

```
 #include <stdio.h> 

 int array[5] ;

 int main ( void )
 {

  array[-1] = array[-1] ; // sound strange ??

  printf ( "%d" , array[-1] ) ; // but work !!
  return 0 ;
 }
```

array in this case in an address, and you get number
before or after that address, but this is undefined behavior
unless you know what you do. Pointer works with ++ or -- !

Comment: Please look up the assembly code generated for `array[-1]` before making such "predictions" ;-)

Comment: array[-1] = 1234  ;
 leaq array(%rip), %rax ;
 movl $1234, -4(%rax) ; gcc 4.7

Comment: Oh yes, it works (32bit): `mov eax,4; imul ecx,eax,0FFFFFFFFh; mov dword ptr array[ecx],4D2h;`. I stand corrected!

Answer (score 1):

It's very clear from other answers that this constitutes **some kind of vulnerability** to your program.

What can be learned from this? Lets assume:

```
 int func(void) 
{
 char buffer[1];
 ...
```

In almost every implementation of the C compiler, the code generated here will create a local stack area and **enables you to access** this stack by the address given in `buffer`. On this stack reside other **important data** too, for example: the **address of the next code** line to be executed after the function returns to it's caller.

You could, therefore, *theoretically*:

- Enter a lot of code into your input function,
- Create a code that defines (in binary code) a new function that does something ugly,
- Overwrite the correct return address (on the stack) with the address that the new function would have if you write it beyond the buffers bounds.

This is called **[buffer overflow exploit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow)**, you can read up [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2902) (and on many other places).

Answer (score 1):

**Yes it is allowed in C, as there is no bound checking.**